# Concatenate Nested Array after Mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with several category objects, each of which has an `items` property containing an array of item objects.  I want to map each item in each category to an object[] with objects that have the properties value and label.  For some reason, I can't perform the concatenation.

```
var categories = [{
                name: "category1",
                items: [{
                    itemId: 1,
                    name: "Item1"
                }, {
                    itemId: 2,
                    name: "Item2"
                }]
            }, {
                name: "category2",
                items: [{
                    itemId: 3,
                    name: "Item3"
                }, {
                    itemId: 4,
                    name: "Item4"
                }]
            }];

var items = [];
for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
    items.concat($.map(categories[i].items,function(elem){
        return {value:elem.itemId, label:elem.name};
    }));
} 
console.log(items); //prints []
```

**Expected Result**

```
[{
   label: "Item1",
   value: "1"
},
{
   label: "Item2",
   value: "2"
},{
   label: "Item3",
   value: "3"
},{
   label: "Item4",
   value: "4"
}
```

I feel as if I am missing something very basic.  I logged the result of the `$.map` function and it appears to be returning an `[]`.  Can anyone figure out the issue?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vymJv/

Comment: Please disregard.  I needed to assign items the result of the concat()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The concat() method is used to join two or more arrays.
>
> This method does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new
>   array, containing the values of the joined arrays.

http://jsfiddle.net/vymJv/1/

```
for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
    items = items.concat($.map(categories[i].items, function(elem) {
        return {value: elem.itemId, label: elem.name};
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realized this shortly after I posted.  I guess I needed to lay it out.  I will accept in a few.

Answer (score 29):

Another method using straight Javascript:

```
var x = categories.map(function(val) {
  return val.items;
}).reduce(function(pre, cur) {
   return pre.concat(cur);
}).map(function(e,i) {
  return {label:e.name,value:e.itemId};
});
```

Output: `x = [{label: "Item1", value: 1}, {label: "Item2", value: 2}, …]`

Comment: Shorter, ES6+ version of this:

var x = categories.map(val => val.items).reduce((pre, cur) => pre.concat(cur)).map(e => ({label: e.name, value: e.itemId}));

Answer (score 14):

updated with `flatMap`(not compatible with IE)

```
categories.flatMap((categories) => categories.items)
```

flatMap() method returns a new array formed by applying a given callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening the result by one level.

Comment: this did the trick, not sure why this answer is not the top one

Answer (score 4):

This piece of code solves your task using a functional programming approach:

```
var items = [].concat.apply([], categories.map(cat =>
  cat.items.map(elem => ({ value:elem.itemId, label:elem.name })))
)
```

Explanation: [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) has the syntax `fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])` and lets us provide parameters to a function in an array. [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) combines an arbitrary amount of parameters into one array. If we now write `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [category1Items, ..., categoryNItems])`, it actually equals `[].concat(category1Items, ..., categoryNItems)`, which concatenates all parameters together. You can also replace `Array.prototype.concat` by `[].concat` to keep it shorter. Otherwise we just use standard mapping to get the job done.

You could also split the code apart a bit more for clarity:

```
function getItem(elem){
  return {value:elem.itemId, label:elem.name};
}

function getCategoryItems(cat) {
  return cat.items.map(getItem);
}

function flatten(arr) {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr);
}

var items = flatten(categories.map(getCategoryItems));
```

Comment: Not sure when the syntax was defined, but nowadays `[].concat(...arr)` should achieve the same as your `flatten` definition

Answer (score 4):

```
  const items = categories
          .map(category => category.items)
          .reduce((prev, current) => [...prev, ...current])
          .map((e, i) => ({ label: e.name, value: e.itemId }));
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why.

Answer (score 3):

We could extend the array prototype by creating **concatAll** which will concatenate all of your arrays by iterating over each subarray, dumping each value into a new array.

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
  var results = [];
  this.forEach(function(subArray) {
    subArray.forEach(function(subArrayValue) {
      results.push(subArrayValue);
    });
  });
  return results;
};
```

Then, we can get the desired result with the following:

```
let items = categories.map(function(category) {
  return category.items.map(function(item) {
    return {label: item.name, value: item.itemId};
  });
}).concatAll();
```

We get the items by translating each category into an array of items. Because we have two categories, we will end up with two arrays of items. By applying **concatAll** on the final result, we flatten those two arrays of items and get the desired output.